# Hibernate: Partial fetching of collection?

Tags: hibernate, collections, fetch, partial

I would like to fetch only parts of the a collection using a hibernate criteria query. As an example lets say i have a Class object containing multiple Student objects. Now i would like to get a list of classes but only the german students should be fetched into the students collection (the rest is not needed and would be massive overhead) with just one database query.

In later versions of hibernate (i think before 3.6.4) this could be done by using a filtered createCriteria like this:

```
criteria.createCriteria("students", "studentscollection", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN,
     Restrictions.eq("studentscollection.country", "DE"));
```

The problem is that in current versions of hibernate this leaves the collection uninitialized and triggers massive database queries to load the whole collections for every single collection on access. This is a massive performance problem causing hundreds of queries instead of one.

Is there any solution in current hibernate versions to get this done using one query?

Answer (score 0):

Consider staying with lower version of hibernate. We had similar dilemmas in my team recently. As far as I remember I used similar structures with the version 4.0.1 final and don't remember any problems with multiple queries/ efficiency. But you are right that the behaviour in version 3.6.4 could be changed ([https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2049?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2049?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)) let us know here if you would find the answer for this.

Greetings,

Lukasz

Comment: As far as i can tell every version after and including 3.6.4

Comment: Yes i think that this change was intended. I already commented the jira entry HHH-2049 and asked to get a flag to tell hibernate that i actually want the old behaviour but i don't think it will be implemented. Staying at older hibernate versions is not really an option at long sight...